How does the grammar in 这不关你的事 work?

这不关你的事。
That's none of your business.

Judging from YouDao, etc., this counts a complete sentence.  I'm trying to figure out how the grammar breaks down here, and in particular, what the attributive (定语) is here.
I'd naturally parse 不关你的事 as

不关你 (attributive) + 的 + 事 (object)

but then the sentence would just be two consecutive noun phrases, which cannot be correct.  If 关 is interpreted as a verb, then, the sentence would break down as:

这 (subject) + 不关 (verb) + 你 (attributive) + 的 + 事 (object)

but this would also imply my interpretation of sentences like (source: YouDao):

我没告诉她们有关你的事情。
他们问了许多有关中国的问题。

are inaccurate, because here I would interpret 有关 as being part of the attributive, e.g., 有关中国 (attributive) + 的 + 问题.
My current best guess is that in 这不关你的事, the 不关 is short/slang for 不是有关（于）, in which case the sentence would be equivalent to:

这不是有关你的事。

Question: How does the grammar in 这不关你的事 work?

This is interesting. Long before a classmate translated "It is none of your business" into 关你屁事。

I don’t understand why you think seeing 不关 as a simple negated verb implies your interpretation of 有关 as a modifier (part of the attribute) is inaccurate. They’re different structures, used in different ways, and implying different word classes for 关 (verb in the first, noun in the second), so the two interpretations don’t really influence each other at all.

关 (V): to concern/involve
Used in a main clause:

这 + 不关 + 你的事 =
This + doesn't concern + your business >> This is none of your business

Used in a relative clause:

这 + 是 + [不关+你] 的事 =
This is business [that doesn't concern you]


 有关 (VN): to have a connection with, to have a bearing on
Used in a main clause:

这事 + 与你 + 没关 =
This business + has nothing to do + with you

Used in a relative clause:

这 + 是 + [与你+没关] 的事 =
This + is + business that [+ has got nothing to do + with you] Or to use your example:
这 + 是 + [有关+中国] 的问题 =
This + is + an issue that [+ has got something to do + with China]


Question: How does the grammar in 这不关你的事 work?
and also
Question: How does the grammar in 我没告诉她们有关你的事情 work?
First, 关 in the first sentence means "relate to". It is similar to "关系" or "关心”. But 不关 is a very negative saying, which means "go away" or "get lost". Indeed，这不关你的事 means "It is none of your business." 这 (subject) + 不关 (verb) + 你的 (adjective)  + 事 (object)
In the second sentence, 有关 means “about”. It is similar to "关于". It is used as a preposition. 有关你的事情 means things or information about you. It is a noun phrase used as a complement to the verb 告诉。 You can not say 不有关, 不关于. Instead, you say 这不是有关你的事情.

My two cents: (admittedly I am not familiar with Chinese grammar)
定语是用来修饰、限定、说明名词或代词的品质与特征的。名词、代词、形容词、数量词、分词、动名词等都可以做定语。在句子中，定语用于修饰主语和宾语。一般定语的位置在主语和宾语的前面。https://www.en998.com/g/dingyu/dingyu-1.html
In my view, all of your examples are in the form - "主語" + [动詞] + (名词所有格作定语) + 宾语.

"这"+[不关]+(你的)+事.

"我没告诉她们"+[有关]+(你的)+事情。

"他们问了许多"+[有关]+(中国的)+问题。


Lastly, 这不关你的事 = 这事與你無关 (This thing does not concern you)

定语在被修饰的名词前面。名词做主语或者宾语。

YouDao's explanations can indeed be inaccurate.
You can't translate it word by word because Chinese usually has a different way of expressing the same thing as English. I hope this makes sense to you:

这(This) + 不(doesn't) + 关(concern) + 你的(your) + 事(business)。 =
That's none of your business.


我(I) + 没(didn't) + 告诉(tell) + 她们(them) + 有关你的事情(things about you)。 =
I told them nothing about you.

In Chinese, attributives always come before objects, so

有关(about) + 你(you) + 的 + 事情(things) =
things about you

Here, "有关你的" is an attributive phrase.
Similarly:

他们(They) + 问了(asked) + 许多(lots of) + 有关中国的问题(questions about China)。 =
They asked lots of questions about China.

"关" can be interpreted as "relationship", so:
"有关" = "has relationship to" = "about" = "concern" = "relate to".
"关于" is similar to "有关" but is closer to "about".
"的" is a common suffix for any attributive. eg.:
"红色" = "red" as noun,
"红色的" = "red" as attributive.

关：合拢，闭门 [shut;close] originally represents a door bolt
关：关心 [be concerned with]。literally: shut in your heart

如:关应(关顾照应);关意(放在心上);关思(留心思考);关念(关心挂念)

这不关你的事。
This doesn't concern you.
这: a pointer, refers to something in the context: maybe a locked room in the office, you want to know what is in there. (Maybe the boss keeps his mad wife locked in there!)
不: negates the following
关：关心：concern
你: you, your, a descriptor for 事
的: that, those
事: thing(s)
关心: literally: shut in your heart reminds me of a lovely old German poem:
Du bist mein, ich bin dein. You are mein, I am yours
Dessen sollst du gewiss sein. Of that you can be sure
Du bist eingeschlossen You are locked
in meinem Herzen, in my heart
verloren ist das Schlüssellein: lost is the key
Du musst auch für immer darin bleiben. You must forever stay in there.
